# Websphere admin login got deleted. How to set it back?

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

I had written a code to delete login users from PUMA. Unfortunately due to a bug in the code, the admin login got deleted. How to set it back?

Comment: Did you delete the user from the registry, or the role binding for access control? What user registries are you using? I assume this is WAS Classic rather than WAS Liberty?

Comment: deleted using java code from PumaController. (IBMPumaUtilities)

Comment: I'm not sure what that works, but you probably need to recreate these accounts. It should be possible if you use wsadmin and connect locally to the deployment Manager (I'm assuming there is a cell) using -conntype=none you'll probably have to restart and sync config for everything after this though.

Comment: usually it depends on the registry attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

The login never gets deleted by deleting through PUMA Utilities. Only its password gets reset. 
It can be retrieved back by logging in to the console and Under Manage users--> Select this user and change the password.
It worked fine then for me!