# How to make the Administration tab visible in admin login in Websphere Application Server?

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, websphere-portal

The admin login for deploying war files in Websphere portal got deleted due to a bug in code. We have another admin login but here, the "Administration" tab wherein we can deploy web modules and manage pages is not visible here. How to make that tab visible?

When we login with hostname:port/wps/myportal as an admin, we can see a tab named "Administration" under which there is something called as "Web Module" where we can deploy war files. "Manage Pages" where in we can assign portlets.. That tab "Administration" isn't visible. I need to make that visible.

I mean this page: 
https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1isTDAZ4dIppNpQWEGzQADZxermMMUKJZZZuqGAOLOcc/edit?usp=sharing

I'm unable to view the above page anymore. How do I make this "Administration" tab visible?

Comment: did you mean getting the WebSphere Portal administration section visible inside of the WebSphere Admin console?

Comment: not in WAS console..in the Websphere aplication server.

Comment: it is still unclear to me. WebSphere Admin console means in my terms https://hostname:port/ibm/console which is in the WebSphere Application server. Maybe you could add some more details to the Question. It would help my to understand your problem

Comment: When we login with hostname:port/wps/myportal as an admin, we can see a tab named "Administration" under which there is something called as "Web Module" where we can deploy war files. "Manage Pages" where in we can assign portlets..
That tab "Administration" isn't visible. I need to make that visible.

Comment: i mean..websphere portal server

Answer (score 0):

There are two options
1. you can follow one of the answers in this question
[websphere-admin-login-
got-deleted-how-to-set-it-back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31848663/websphere-admin-login-%20got-deleted-how-to-set-it-back)

and issue the following command:

> ConfigEngine wp-change-portal-admin-user -DnewAdminId=
>   -DnewAdminPw=-DnewAdminGroupId= -Dskip.ldap.validation=true

2. WebSphere Portal does have as well a Portal Admin Group. Each member of this group gets full access to all elements like the Administration section
   By assigning your second "admin" user into this group he will get the proper authority

Comment: the second admin user is in the admin group